# Photoshop: How to reverse normals of 3d layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I am using Photoshop CS5 and created a cylinder 3d layer (3D -> New Shape from Layer) from a seamless clouds texture. I wanted the image to be warped like a tube, and succeeded, but the tube is convex; I want to be looking at the INTERIOR surface of the tube. This is a common procedure in 3d modeling programs called "flip normals" or "reverse normals". How can I do this in Photoshop?

Extra notes:

- This has nothing to do with generating a "normal map" for a 3d model, this is using newer 3d object features, which can map 2d layers to 3d objects, generated within Photoshop.
- I can settle for a displacement filter that "wraps" the edges of the layer, but I don't see anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop is not the best package for creating 3D objects, it's not a complete 3D editor. As far as I know, you can't. You can either:

1. Create the tube using an extruded ring, so you have normals facing inside.

   1. Select a shape layer (a vector ring in this case)
   2. Choose **3D** > **New 3D Extrusion** From Selected Path, Layer, or Current Selection.
2. Get a 3D software and create your 3D shape there, where you'll have better control of the model. For a simple tube there are many free 3D softwares that would work.
3. If you have an Adobe CC subscription: Go to After Effects, from there select **File** > **New** > **Maxon CINEMA 4D File** or **Layer** > **New** > **Maxon CINEMA 4D File**. You can then render your cylinder and re-import to Photoshop if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this by rendering a rotating seamless cylinder in Unity, back in November

Comment: Yeah sorry for the late reply, I don't think I saw the question earlier.